# Why didn't Dabura attempt to turn Buu to stone?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In the DBZ episode [**Meal Time**](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Meal_Time), why didn't Dabura even try to turn Majin Buu into stone? I'm not saying or implying it would have worked, but it seemed more likely to work than anything else he did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the episode *Meal Time*, Dabura actually did try to turn Buu into stone by using his spit. But when he did, Buu dodged the attack, then turned him into a cookie and ate him.

If Buu was hit by the stone spit from Dabura, he would be able to regenerate after breaking like Piccolo did.

> In desperation, Dabura tries to turn Buu to stone with his spit. Buu
>   dodges and turns him into a huge cookie with his Chocolate Beam,
>   eating him afterwards.

This is found on [the same page](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Meal_Time) that you posted in the question.

Comment: I seem to have missed that sequence... the description came after Ero's edit which altered the link